# How to install pdflib in xampp?

Tags: php, pdf, xampp, installation, pdflib

I want to install [pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-9/) on my xamppserver.
I download pdflib 9 and copied php_pdflib.dll and pasted on ext. Also I have added extension=php_pdflib.dll in php.ini, but I am still getting error message.

Comment: Which error messag to you get?

Comment: "The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem" @martin

Answer (score 1):

You need to see in phpinfo() output, which version of php you have and if php version and compiler matches  the version of PDFlib - everything should work fine.